# How do i call a spcific jquery function form within another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which is not working

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    function effects(content_name,active_name)
    {
    // switch all tabs off
        $(active_name).removeClass("active");

    // switch this tab on
        $(this).addClass("active");

    // slide all content up
        $(content_name).slideUp();

    // slide this content up
        var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#"+content_show).slideDown();

    }

    $("a.tab_1").click(function () {    
        var content_name = '.content_a';
        var active_name = 'a.tab_1.active';
        effects(content_name,active_name);

    });
            $("a.tab_2").click(function () {    
        var content_name = '.content_b';
        var active_name = 'a.tab_2.active';
        effects(content_name,active_name);

    });
            $("a.tab_3").click(function () {    
        var content_name = '.content_c';
        var active_name = 'a.tab_3.active';
        effects(content_name,active_name);//create effects with the content         
    });
});
```

Its a set of tab groups upto 8 in number. Writing individual functions will have an adverse effect on loading time.

***Answer 2 hours later:***

Thank you all for pointing out the "effetcs" mistake in the code.

The other mistake was I was doing was not passing "$(this)" as a parameter into the called function "effects".

I Have adjoined the link where the necessary changes are done and the code works.

[jsfiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/phyGS/2/

Comment: Replace `effetcs` with `effects`, at the first `click` block.

Comment: What means 'not working'? Could you provide an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: *"...which is not working..."* Asking Technical Questions 101: Not working ***how***? What do you expect it to do? What is it doing instead? Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console? What have you tried to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `effetcs` with `effects` at the first block, and replace every occurrence of

```
effects(content_name,active_name);
```

with

```
effects.call(this, content_name, active_name);
```

This [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method assigns a new value to the `this` property of function `effects`.